# Discord.Net 2.0 send message to specific channel

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

```
Public Async Function Kick(ByVal user As IGuildUser, <Remainder> ByVal reason As String) As Task
        Dim guild = Context.Guild
        Dim bot = Context.Client
        Dim message = Context.Message
        Dim u = Context.User
'Channel Info
        Dim _client As New DiscordSocketClient
        Dim id As ULong = 1235234987 'Random numbers not a channel id
        Dim chnl As IMessageChannel = _client.GetChannel(id)

        If u.Id = "id" Or "id" Or "id" Then

            Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
                .Author = New EmbedAuthorBuilder With {
                .IconUrl = u.GetAvatarUrl,
                .Name = u.Username
            },
            .Title = $"{user.Username}#{user.Discriminator}'s Kick Information",
            .ImageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vc241Ku.jpeg",
            .Description = reason,
            .Color = New Color(masterClass.randomEmbedColor),
            .ThumbnailUrl = user.GetAvatarUrl,
            .Timestamp = Context.Message.Timestamp,
            .Footer = New EmbedFooterBuilder With {
                    .Text = "Kick Data",
                    .IconUrl = guild.IconUrl
                }
            }

            Await chnl.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
            Await user.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
            Await user.KickAsync(reason)
        Else

            Await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You do not match the IDs that are required for this. Bye.")
        End If



    End Function
```

This is my kick command, how would I make it so it sends the embed to a specific channel? I already have it set so it sends the user the embed but I would like for it to now send that embed to a certain channel in the server. Also a side note. Does anyone know where I could have the bot hosted online instead of self hosting or a good tutorial on where I could host it?

Comment: Get the channel  you want from the `Guild` and call `SendMessage` on that . The guild has methods available such as `GetTextChannel`

Comment: when I do guild.GetTextChannelAsync(id).SendMessage("message"). it tells me "SendMessage is not part of Task(of ITextChannel)"

Comment: Because it isn't... didn't Intellisense show the method as SendMessageAsync() ? Also, you can't call the method on the Task. You need to call it on the actual TextChannel. If you used a SocketGuild instance, you won't need the Async method GetTextchannelAsync....instead you could use GetTextChannel

Comment: when I do guild.GetText the only one that shows is GetTextChannelAsync. When in those says nothing about message. when I do Context.Guild.Get  it is the same result.

Comment: Then your guild is not of type SocketGuild, probably because your context isn't SocketCommandContext. If you are using the Async method you need to Await it, like you should any Async Task

Comment: I figured it out. The issue is I had some conflicting code which not let me get the correct properties.

Comment: Sorry again..... It actually doesn't work. I get no errors. Just now when the command is executed nothing happens. I added g as SocketGuild in the function parameters. and now have Await g.GetTextChannel(id).SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.build()) but now after running the command nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Public Async Function Kick(ByVal user As IGuildUser, <Remainder> ByVal reason As String) As Task
    Dim guild = Context.Guild
    Dim chnl = guild.GetTextChannel(123456789)
    Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
        .Author = New EmbedAuthorBuilder With {
            .IconUrl = user.GetAvatarUrl,
            .Name = user.Username
        },
        .Title = $"{user.toString()}'s Kick Information",
        .ImageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vc241Ku.jpeg",
        .Description = reason,
        .Color = New Color(masterClass.randomEmbedColor),
        .ThumbnailUrl = user.GetAvatarUrl,
        .Timestamp = Context.Message.Timestamp,
        .Footer = New EmbedFooterBuilder With {
                        .Text = "Kick Data",
                        .IconUrl = guild.IconUrl
                    }
        }

    Await chnl.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
    Await user.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
    Await user.KickAsync(reason)
End Function
```

Comment: https://hastebin.com/hejagiwaxa.properties this is the entire class. When I try to do guild.GetTextChannel(id) I get nothing about SendMessage. so added g as SocketGuild in the function parameters which then gave me the correct properties for GetTextChannel. but when I try to execute the command nothing happens. I am using discord.net v2.2.0

Comment: like i said in a previous comment your context isn't that of SocketCommandContext. You should use `Inherits ModuleBase(Of SocketCommandContext)`. You can't just add a random parameter to your command methods. Anything you add there needs to be included in the message that invokes the command.

Comment: Okay, added (Of SocketCommandContext) to ModuleBase. and created the variable chnl = Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(id), and then did Await chnl.SendMessageAsync(). But I get the same result nothing is executed.

Comment: so at this point you need to debug your code and see what's happening. Also, make sure you are properly logging errors. Just a side not the SocketGuild argument should be removed from you method signature if you didn't do so already

Comment: okay... Issue is sending to the desired channel. If I want to send the message to where the command was executed and send the user a dm of the embed it wall works. Just when adding (Of SocketCommandContext) does it not want to execute. Not sure how to log any errors if the bot has any. And yes I've removed the SocketGuild parameter. Thanks for trying to help me with something that seems really simple..

Comment: Debug the code...use breakpoints, step through line by line.. check what `Dim chnl = guild.GetTextChannel(123456789)` returns. Does it actually get a channel... when you call SendMessage, does the code continue to the next line or does it exit prematurely? Thing don't just "not work" it will either throw an error or do something you didn't expect it to do... it should never "do nothing"

Comment: Sorry just can't seem to figure it out.... https://i.imgur.com/tv6hGi8.png . Even though I've been coding for almost 4 years now I can't seem to even figure out how to debug my own code or even how to use breakpoints. Been watching quick videos on how to use them but theirs does step by step while mine doesn't stop. I placed the breakpoints on where I think would be good to have them but nothing changes. just executes it without stopping.

Comment: Your `If` statement isn't valid. Does the first breakpoint even get hit? You use F10 to have your debugger execute line by line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: no. Says break always (currently 0) when doing the command. When doing F10 it takes me to where the bot gets run in a separate file. then after pressing it again it runs the bot. then when I use the command. nothing happens.

Comment: hello sorry if I'm annoying you. but just a little update. On any command, I try when I add (Of SocketCommandContext) they no longer work. I tried it with my purge command and the command didn't delete any messages. It didn't do anything actually. In the output window if vs it says "code has exited with code 0". Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: No, that does not help.. How do you create context in your command handler? You would really benefit from understanding how to debug your code and probably some error logging btw

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Anu6is/DiscordBotExample/tree/master/Example2-Services) is a basic example of a bot with logging and dependency injection.